# groupBy to arrays by value, includes(), custom structure

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I need to check through a list of routes and group them by path, like `/mens` becomes a "parent route" for all the others containing `/mens` and so on... The wanted result I would like is this,

```
const newRoutes = {
  "/kids": [{
    "path": "/kids",
    "name": "kids-clothing-section",
    "children": [{
        "path": "/kids/shoes",
        "name": "kids-clothing-shoes",
      },
      {
        "path": "/kids/shirts",
        "name": "kids-clothing-shirts",
      }
    ]
  }]
}
```

I know how to groupBy with both with vanilla javascript (reduce) and with lodash (`_.groupBy()`). But the rest is too complex for me, the part with matching on path `/path` parent especially. So really greatfull for any help with it!

**EDIT**
So that not all routes are children to "home", I thought there would be a length check `path.lenght > 3`.

```js
const routes = [{
    path: '/',
    name: 'home',
  },
  {
    path: '/about',
    name: 'about',
  },
  {
    path: '/mens',
    name: 'mens-clothing-section',
  },
  {
    path: '/mens/shoes',
    name: 'mens-clothing-shoes',
  },
  {
    path: '/mens/shoes/:id',
    name: 'mens-clothing-shoes-details'
  },
  {
    path: '/kids',
    name: 'kids-clothing-section',
  },
  {
    path: '/kids/shoes',
    name: 'kids-clothing-shoes',
  },
  {
    path: '/kids/jeans',
    name: 'kids-clothing-jeans',
  },
  {
    path: '/kids/shirts',
    name: 'kids-clothing-shirts',
  },
  {
    path: '/kids/shoes/:id',
    name: 'kids-clothing-shoes-details'
  }
]



const groupedRoutes = routes.reduce(function(obj, route) {
  // get the path of the route
  const path = route.path

  const splitted = path.split('/')[1]

  if (!obj.hasOwnProperty(splitted)) {
    obj[splitted] = []
  }

  obj[splitted].push(route)

  return obj
}, {})

console.log(groupedRoutes)
```

Comment: what is with the home directory? should all directories are children of the home directory?

Comment: @NinaScholz Thanks for bringing that to my attention, I forgot to write it in the initial post. Updated my question :)

Comment: btw, your result has a mixed style of object with sub path name and children arrays with objects. what happens to the children of the children? please add the wanted result to the given data.

Comment: @NinaScholz 2nd child could be flat under the parent, `parent > children`

Comment: Is the array of `"/kids": [{}]` needed into your result ?

Comment: yes I need to be able to loop though the results

Comment: But I don't understand what you can have as second value in this array. Because you put everything (/kids*) into the children of the first element of the array

Comment: It looks more logic to have this result. Is it not ? `const newRoutes = [
  {
    "path": "/kids",
    "name": "kids-clothing-section",
    "children": [
        {
        "path": "/kids/shoes",
        "name": "kids-clothing-shoes",
      },
      {
        "path": "/kids/shirts",
        "name": "kids-clothing-shirts",
      }
    ]
  }
];`
?

Comment: @Gilsdav you are correct! That makes more sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe this works for you by using an array as result set.

```js
const
    routes = [{ path: '/', name: 'home' }, { path: '/about', name: 'about' }, { path: '/mens', name: 'mens-clothing-section' }, { path: '/mens/shoes', name: 'mens-clothing-shoes' }, { path: '/mens/shoes/:id', name: 'mens-clothing-shoes-details' }, { path: '/kids', name: 'kids-clothing-section' }, { path: '/kids/shoes', name: 'kids-clothing-shoes' }, { path: '/kids/jeans', name: 'kids-clothing-jeans' }, { path: '/kids/shirts', name: 'kids-clothing-shirts' }, { path: '/kids/shoes/:id', name: 'kids-clothing-shoes-details' }],
    groupedRoutes = routes.reduce(function (r, { path, name }) {
        path
            .split(/(?=\/)/)
            .reduce((a, _, i, p) => {
                var path = p.slice(0, i + 1).join(''),
                    item = a.find(q => q.path === path);

                if (!item) a.push(item = { path, name, children: [] });
                return item.children;
            }, r);            
        return r;
    }, []);
 
   console.log(groupedRoutes);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Without unnecessary children.

```js
const
    routes = [{ path: '/', name: 'home' }, { path: '/about', name: 'about' }, { path: '/mens', name: 'mens-clothing-section' }, { path: '/mens/shoes', name: 'mens-clothing-shoes' }, { path: '/mens/shoes/:id', name: 'mens-clothing-shoes-details' }, { path: '/kids', name: 'kids-clothing-section' }, { path: '/kids/shoes', name: 'kids-clothing-shoes' }, { path: '/kids/jeans', name: 'kids-clothing-jeans' }, { path: '/kids/shirts', name: 'kids-clothing-shirts' }, { path: '/kids/shoes/:id', name: 'kids-clothing-shoes-details' }],
    groupedRoutes = routes.reduce(function (r, { path, name }) {
        path
            .split(/(?=\/)/)
            .reduce((o, _, i, p) => {
                var path = p.slice(0, i + 1).join(''),
                    item = (o.children = o.children || []).find(q => q.path === path);

                if (!item) o.children.push(item = { path, name });
                return item;
            }, r);            
        return r;
    }, { children: [] }).children;
 
   console.log(groupedRoutes);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: My intuition says everything except `"/"` should probably be a direct (or indirect) child of `"/"`

Comment: I'm not saying your answer is wrong. I just think the OP hasn't thought this through very well...

Comment: @user633183 I have, for my specific use that is the structure I need. The home route is not the parent to all children, it stand on it's own. It just happens to be the first route hence `/`, could of been `/home`

Comment: @Dejan.S the structure is inconsistent and therefore any program that processes it must deal with the inconsistency. Maybe it's not your choice, but it's effectively wrong. A well-defined consistent structure is always better.

Comment: I'll try this out. I'm curious to learn, in the second reduce `reduce((o, _, i, p)` what do the params represent here?

Comment: `o` is the accumulator, an object of the last matching path, underscore denotes an unused parameter, `i` is an index and `p` is the reference to the looping array.

Comment: @user633183 why would it be? `/` could be `/home`, same as `/about`. I'm not saying you are wrong just curious to why?

Comment: Dejan.S, before you edited your question, I think you were closer to a more ideal structure - `{ "": { path: "/", name: "home", children: { "kids": { path: "/kids", name: "kids", children: { "shoes": { path: "/kids/shoes", name: "kids shoes" }, "shirts": { path: "/kids/shirts", name: "kids shirts" }, ... } }, "mens": { path: "/mens", name: "mens", children: { ... } }, ... } }` - NB because objects are used, you can lookup a node in `O(log n)` vs the much slower array search, `O(n)`. Further `path` could be removed as it is redundant.

Comment: @user633183 that makes sense as well. If it's not too much to ask but do you know how to do that? I have started it with grouping but I'm not sure how to make the structure and keep track on what has been before.